# How to click on JavaScript Alert on top of the browser

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

After click on the link **please update flashplayer** , Alert opens but the code cannot able to click on the **Allow** button. I am getting error. org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open

Screenshot are attached here[Allow Flash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4uDs.png)

Comment: It's not Javascript alert. It's Browser alert and I doubt you can handle it with Selenium

Answer (score 0):

You can't click on the browser prompt, but you can enable flash so that the prompt will never appear. Not something I've done before, but hopefully this link will send you in the right direction.

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30312/enable-flash-player-on-chrome-62-while-running-selenium-test

Good luck!